# Vue - Unable to use variable in template

Tags: vue.js, variables

I have this code in my VUE file:

```
<template>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <section class="list">
            <draggable class="drag-area" :list="picsNew" :options="{animation:200, group:'status'}" :element="'article'" @add="onAdd($event, false)"  @change="update">
                <article class="card" v-for="(photo, index) in picsNew" :key="photo.id" :data-id="photo.id">
                    <header>
                        {{ this.galCode }}{{ photo.filename }}
                    </header>
                </article>
            </draggable>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
export default {
    components: {
        draggable
    },

    props: ['myPics', 'galId', 'phCode', 'galCode'],


    data() {
        return {
            picsNew: this.myPics,
        }
    },
    methods: {

        update() {
            this.picsNew.map((photo, index) => {
                photo.order = index + 1;
            });


            let photos = this.picsNew;

            console.log(this.galCode)
            axios.put('/gallery/' + this.galId + '/updateAll', {
                photos: photos
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

in the template, photo.filename works, but this.galCode throws these two errors:

```
app.js:44152 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'galCode' of undefined"

found in

 ---> <DraggablePic> at resources/js/components/draggablepic.vue

app.js:45415 TypeError: Cannot read property 'galCode' of undefined
```

The variable contains a value, as i am printing it to console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access props variable directly from your template. To solve this, initalize a state variable (under data {}) Within props value as default like you did With `picsNeW`.
another remark, avoid to use "this" from template, you should access directly datas form its name. Use default value in your props, this is recommended :)

Comment: you mean like the picsNew variable?

Answer (score 2):

The line  `{{ this.galCode }}{{ photo.filename }}` should be  `{{ galCode }}{{ photo.filename }}`. Your problem is the `this` you added

Answer (score 1):

First you should define Default value as :

```
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default'
    },
    ...
    galCode: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
  },
```

Second be sure you receive desired data, specially in nested object you should check the object defined to prevent receive undefined property error, like use `v-if` :

```
<header>
    <template v-if="galCode">{{ galCode }}</template>    // can use v-else here too print default value
    <template v-if="photo.filename"> {{ photo.filename }}</template>

</header>
```